# Is there a way to read a value from a Java process using C++?

Tags: java, c++, variables

I'm working on a **C++ application that needs to get some info from a Java process**.

I'm already using **pointers to get data from the memory** of a certain module that doesn't run on java. I figured out this wasn't possible with java because of the way it switches memory addresses around, so **I was wondering if I could do something similar to get the value of a java variable**.

I can access the source code of the java application, but my code should be able to get values from the original one.

Everything I've done so far is based on a 64bit windows console application.

Comment: I would avoid using shared memory unless dealing with a *very* performance critical application (which I doubt is the case since you are using Java).  Communicating via a socket or a file (depending which direction(s) you need to communicate) will be a lot easier.

Comment: @0x5453 That would be my go-to solution, but I can't edit the java application i need to get data from.

Comment: Just adding that interfacing to and from a C++ application, a file will be easiest, since sockets in C++ are quite tedious.
If you can't edit the java application, then you will have to work around or with the JVM itself...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to share random access memory across applications, however file I/O would probably work just fine. There are good tutorials for file I/O in both of those languages if you haven't done it before.

Write to the file in java:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io

Read from the file in C++:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't edit the java application itself, so this wouldn't work for me.

So far I'm using ReadProcessMemory() to get some of the info I need, but this only works for the modules that don't run on java.

Comment: If you have the source code what's stopping you from changing it?

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally any interaction between C/C++ and Java makes me look to JNI. Java JNI has options for integration in either direction, depending if you can modify code or not.

If you can't modify the Java app, but you can invoke Java app in order to create the process, then you may consider the invocation API to embed a JVM into your C++ app. Once you do that, you can use the API to access various things in the Java app.

A good example already exists:  **https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html**

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll look into it and see if I manage to get it working with JNI